# FuncName(){} vs function FuncName() {}

Tags: bash-script

There is two ways to define function in bash script.

1.

```
function FuncName() {
    echo "$FUNCNAME"
}
```

2.

```
FuncName() {
    echo "$FUNCNAME"
}
```

So my questions is what's the different between in this and which one should be use.

Comment: I'm having a hard time locating it but appa